# Is it possible to know that an Android webview allows autoplay?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, html5-video

Generally, it is a well known fact that you cannot autoplay video withing an mobile browser or a `WebView`.

A less known fact is that Android 4.2 (API 17) and above, provides the following API, that allows autoplaying video in that specific WebView.

```
webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

I wonder if it is possible for the JavaScript code running in a webview to know whether autoplay is possible or not.

I know (?) that I can't access the `WebSettings` object, but maybe I could query some attributes of the video object and deduct it from there?